# GET syntax in xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to use a parameter that I pass to the page in an xpath query.  This works properly (hard coded):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("bookstore.xml");

$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = 'Everyday Italian']"); 

echo $res[0]->author

?>
```

but I pass the parameter with:

```
bookdetails.php?title="Everyday Italian"
```

and then do:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("bookstore.xml");

$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET['title']]"); 

echo $res[0]->author

?>
```

I get a 500 error.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the parameter with `urlencode('bookdetails.php?title=Everyday Italian')` instead.

Comment: I tried this: 
echo "<a href=" . urlencode("bookdetails.php?title=" . $child->title) . ">" . $child->title . "</a> <br/>";
but it also changes the ? and the =, so I think I want this instead:
echo "<a href=bookdetails.php?title=" . urlencode($child->title) . ">" . $child->title . "</a> <br/>";
Thanks! (Is there a way to post code in a comment??)

Comment: TO post code in the comments, or inline code in the questions, you should use backticks (`). BTW, if this answer was correct, you might consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP variable will be expanded into a string value, which should be wrapped in quotes when evaluated in the XPATH expression.

I'm not as familiar with PHP, and unsure how the nested quotes(used to reference the `$_GET` variable) would work when already wrapped with single and double quotes.

I'm assuming that you could build the string by concatenating the string fragments and variable:

```
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = '" . $_GET['title'] . "']");
```

Or, that you could assign the value to a variable that could be referenced without quotes:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("bookstore.xml");
$title = $_GET['title'];
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = '$title']"); 

echo $res[0]->author

?>
```

Comment: Those are great ideas. Unfortunately I still am getting 500 errors using either method. echo $_GET['title'] shows the correct string, so I'm not sure what else could be wrong? (Here is the link: http://ewh.ieee.org/r1/schenectady/Sandbox/phpParameters/bookdetails.php?title=TestBook)

Comment: Hmm, can you echo the details of the error?  The XPATH is correct and should be selecting the `book` element. Maybe it isn't loading the XML file correctly?  Maybe try specifying the full path(physical or URL)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET['title']]");
```

This is incorrect. When interpolating array/hash elements within a double-quoted string, you cannot quote the index value. Either of the following would be correct:

```
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = {$_GET['title']}]"); // surround with {}
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET[title]]"); // remove the '
```

Of course, when not in the context of a double-quoted string, then doing:

```
$res = $_GET[title];
```

will have PHP interpreting 'title' as a constant, which most likely has no defined value, so the code would be interpreted as

```
$res = $_GET[];
```

Comment: Hm,maybe I'm crazy - I thought it was working but I'm back to the 500 error now. The url is:
http://ewh.ieee.org/r1/schenectady/Sandbox/phpParameters/bookdetails.php?title=TestBook

and the line that causes the error is:

$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET[title]]"); 

this line works correctly:
echo $_GET['title']

Any thoughts?

Comment: Anything in the server logs? 500 is "internal server error", which means any debug output would be in the server's error log.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have ftp access to this webserver. Is there a way to "turn on debug outputs" so it displays the log/error in the browser or something like that? These 500 errors are really killing me because I have no idea where to even start to look for the problem (hence my questions here :) ).

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It'd be a webserver setting. You might be able to cobble together a script that can read out the last few lines of the script, if the userID your script runs under has access to the log directory (possible, but not likely). Best bet would be to ask the server operator nicely pretty-please-with-sprinkles if they'd redirect the error log for your host, or at least give you access to the files.

Comment: Another thought: Have you tried hardcoding your query parameter? I see in the "working" example you used single quotes around the title, but in the non-working _GET version, it's double quotes. try `...[title = \"Everyday Italian\"]"` with the escapes. Maybe the xpath library on that server's broken and won't accept double-quoted strings.

Comment: You're right - 
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = \"Everyday Italian\"]"); // works fine
//$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = "Everyday Italian"]");   // 500 error

However, in the GET version we don't have quotes around the title at all, right?
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET[title]]");

Comment: You have double quotes embedded in the URL sample, though... `....php?title="Everyday Italian"`. Those would get pasted into the xpath argument string. Which raises the question of whether the server's (or php's) doing something hinky with those quotes before they get to your xpath call.

Comment: [deleted - my bad. I forgot a semi colon :) ]

Comment: It is amazingly not producing errors anymore, but the output is empty:
$res = $xml->xpath("/bookstore/book[title = $_GET[title]]"); 
echo $res[0]; // displays nothing

Comment: To try to debug I changed it to:
$mystring = "/bookstore/book[title = \"$_GET[title]\"]";
echo $mystring;
$res = $xml->xpath($mystring); 

The output is:
/bookstore/book[title = "TestBook"]

This looks reasonable/correct to me. I had also tried it without the double quotes around the GET, but in both cases $res[0] is empty.

Comment: and what were you passing in on the query line in the browser?